# Ignite thin client auto reconnect doesn't work

Tags: c#, ignite

Configuration on a single machine:
I have single server node

```
<ignite xmlns="http://ignite.apache.org/schema/dotnet/IgniteConfigurationSection" gridName="myGrid1">
<clientConnectorConfiguration port="10800"/>    
<discoverySpi type="TcpDiscoverySpi" localPort='48500' localPortRange='1'>
  <ipFinder type="TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder">
    <endpoints>
      <string>127.0.0.1:48500</string>
    </endpoints>
  </ipFinder>
</discoverySpi>
<communicationSpi type='TcpCommunicationSpi' localPort='48100' />
```

And thin client node:

```
Ignition.StartClient(new IgniteClientConfiguration { Host = "127.0.0.1", Port = 10800})
```

So I'm trying to make a next test:
1) shutdown server node
2) start server node againg
3) check connection from client node to server node

The problem is after 2 step when I call method

```
ignite.GetCache<long,Entity>("cacheName").TryGet(id, out item)
```

I get an exception

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
>    ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size
>    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.SendRequest(RequestMessage& reqMsg)  at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc)  at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc
>    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.TryGet(TK key, TV& value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that automatic reconnect is not supported by .Net thin client.

From the source code, Client is created once right away, which does Handshake once right away. There's no reconnect code in sight. There is an [issue filed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7282) about Failover feature in Apache Ignite JIRA: not just reconnect, but try different node addresses.

This means you will have to check for disconnects and reconnect manually.